# Equilibrium to maximize total tax revenue

Tags: calculus, optimization

The supply and demand equations of a good are given by

Qs= -8+P

Qd=(80/3) - (1/3)P

P is measured in dollars. Suppose the government decides to impose a constant per unit tax of $t on the supplier.

1. Find the equilibrium quantity in terms of t
2. Using the expression found in part 1  find the value of t that maximizes the governments total tax revenue. (Make sure the second order condition is satisfied)

I know equilibrium is when Qs=Qd but I don't know how to implement the t. Do I just add it the end of Qs making it Qs= (-8+P)t?

Answer (score 0):

By imposing the tax, the government causes there to be, in effect, two prices
for this type of good.
One price, $P_s,$ is the amount the supplier receives for each unit sold.
The other price, $P_d,$ is the amount the consumer must pay for each unit purchased.
The prices are related by
$$P_d = P_s + t.$$

As the suppliers receive only $P_s$ per unit, they will produce $Q_s = P_s - 8$ units.
As the consumers pay $P_d$ per unit, they will purchase $Q_d = \frac{80}{3} - \frac12 P_d$
units.

You probably want to use the equation relating the prices to write one price in terms of the other, and then proceed to find the equilibrium as usual.